# How to check if a website is is displaying a message?

Tags: php, debian

I have been trying to create a script to check to see if a website is displaying a message. I have several servers, that I want to check to see if they are working from an external site. I created a page where each of the server will display 'ok' if the script is working, but 'error' if the script isn't working? What could I do to externally check if the ok message, or the error message is being displayed? It is just a blank page with the one word, so there would not be anything else interrupting it. I am trying to create this with PHP.

Comment: cURL is a good place to start. http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: You need to write some code. Because no one here is going to do it for you

Comment: @SchahriarSaffarShargh cURL is unnecessary for this, file_Get_contents is much simpler.

Comment: True. Upvoted your solution.

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. It's hard to get a solution here if you don't provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Use file_get_contents

```
$MyPage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/status/page.php');

if ($MyPage == 'OK'){
  echo 'Website up';
} else {
  echo 'Website Error';
}
```

1 thing I would say is how is a website that is not working going to return a page that says 'error'?  Think about it.